# how to add the caller IP to a webget UriTemplate parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, rest

I can't find a way to add to web get in the uri template parameters.

I'm wring a RESTful service and I need to add to the GET operation the caller IP in order to use in my interface implementation.

I would expect the there is a keyword for that purpose something like "context.Request.UserHostAddress" and that the following attribute would work:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?{context.Request.UserHostAddress})]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it!

you need to add to your implementation the followings:

```
var clientIp = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty??new RemoteEndpointMessageProperty("",0);
```